# Login/password mismatch in Python Login Script

Tags: python

i'm trying to write a login module using Python 2-7. First it registers and creates text file. And when you try to login, it must be login. But when i enter the right username it says wrong username. How can i solve it?

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
print "Hos Geldiniz!"
print "Giris Yapmak icin 1'i"
time.sleep( 1 )
print "Kayit Olmak icin 2'yi tuslayiniz"
sec1 = int(input("--> "))
if sec1 == 2:

ifsec1 = raw_input ("Kullanici Adi Giriniz= ")
dosya = open("kadi.txt","w")
dosya.write(ifsec1)
ifsec2 = raw_input ("Sifre Giriniz= ")
dosya2 = open("sifre.txt","w")
dosya2.write(ifsec2)
print "Basariyla Kayit Olundu!"
print "Giris Yapmak icin programi kapatip aciniz"

if sec1 == 1:

ok1 = open("kadi.txt","r")
ok2 = open("sifre.txt","r")
kadi = raw_input ("Kullanici Adim= ")
if (kadi == ok1):
    sifre = raw_input ("Sifrem= ")
    if (sifre == ok2):
        print kadi + ", Olarak Giris Yapildi"
        print "Hosgeldin, " + kadi
    else:
        print "Yanlis Sifre!"
else:
    print "Yanlis Kullanici Adi!"
```

Comment: note that english text would help to understand the program.

Answer (score 2):

```
ok1 = open("kadi.txt","r")
ok2 = open("sifre.txt","r")
```

your `ok1` and `ok2` variables are not strings but file handles. You're comparing the wrong data.

quickfix (to handle the end-of-line char just in case):

```
ok1 = open("kadi.txt","r").read().rstrip("\n")
ok2 = open("sifre.txt","r").read().rstrip("\n")
```

note that it's customary to use a context manager since python 2.7 so you control exactly when the file is closed (when you exit the `with` block)

```
with open("kadi.txt") as f:
   ok1 = f.read().rstrip("\n")
```